# App Store Connect Analytics vs Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, app-store, app-store-connect, firebase-analytics

I uploaded an app to the app store for 1 week and when I look at the app store analytics, there are 20 downloads, but I see 28 downloads in the firebase analytics. Which gives the correct results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download count would be correct on Appstore, because Firebase counts all downloads as distinct download. On App Store, re-installing the app does not count as distinct download.